# Unknown error on Micron NVME disk

Tags: xubuntu, nvme

Recently I installed Xubuntu 22.04.1 on a system that contains a Micron MTFDHBA512QFD NVMe disk.

The last line on the `smartctl -a` report is the following:

```
Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 256 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0         17     0  0x700c  0x4005      -            0     1     -
```

The error counter increases by 1 every time the system starts.

Is there any way for me to read that log and find out what those errors are and what causes them every time I start the system?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found so far, it seems that there is no actual error. Other brands are facing the same issue and the most official answer to that was by **Transcend**.

Their answer was that some platforms are sending commands unknown to SSD drives during system startup. This results in a corresponding response by the drive saying that it doesn't support those specific commands, and this is recorded in the *SMART Error Logs*. That's all. Drive usage is not affected at all by this issue.

Nevertheless, if anyone else knows something different, please post it.

Comment: Sounds like good information, but a direct link to the Transcend information might be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading and installing [Storage Executive Software for Linux Systems](https://www.micron.com/support/software-and-drivers)?
It might offer more information on the health of the SSD drive, and a firmware upgrade, if available.